# Sealing a vintage cabinet to use in bathroom

Tags: cabinets

We purchased an old China cabinet and removed the top in order to use the bottom as a bathroom vanity.  I was advised to seal the cabinet with a polyurethane in order to protect against moisture.  What kind of wood prep needs to be done before applying the poly?  I've read about "Dr-waxing", cleaning, etc. so it's confusing.  We don't know what type of wood the cabinet is or what type of finish was applied originally.  Can you offer some guidance?
The cabinet is in pretty good condition. There are a few nicks and gouges but I figured we can stain those. Yes, we do want to preserve the existing finish. I have attached two pics. One is the cabinet as we bought it and the other is after we separated the top from the bottom. We want to use the bottom piece for the vanity.
[image]
[image]

Comment: We might be able to help out if you can provide us with a few pictures of the cabinet.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at the [woodworking.se] sister site for _loads_ of info on finishing and refinishing. What condition is the current finish in, and do you want to retain (and protect) it or do you want to remove the existing finish and redo it?

Comment: [Strongly related](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/13217/can-you-apply-polyurethane-on-top-of-wood-that-has-been-treated-with-a-deck-seal)

Comment: Also, [this one](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/6131/what-is-the-best-finish-for-wood-in-a-bathroom/10287#10287).